# How to change color of 3 divs using 3 different arrays

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you change the colors of the 3 divs using the 3 arrays provided when i click the change theme button.

```
<script>
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
var colors1 = ['teal', 'brown', 'tan']
var colors2 = ['orange', 'purple', 'black'];
var boxed = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
   for (i = 0; i < boxed.length; i++) {
        boxed[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        boxed[i].style.width = '100px';
        boxed[i].style.height = '100px';
        boxed[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
});
button.style.cursor = "pointer";
</script>
```

Comment: What is problem in your code.

Comment: It is just randomizing the colors from the 1st array colors only. Its not using array colors1 and colors2

Comment: because of this line boxed[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

Comment: You are only choosing colors from array colors.

Comment: Any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: Please add enough of your html so that we can (easily) recreate your problem.

Comment: Simplest solution is to merge these arrays and then perform operation.

Comment: Do you wish to keep the color arrays separate?

Comment: Add some checking to your code, for starters verify that the boxed[i] isn't undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this-

**Updated code for the requirement**

```js
var colors = [
  ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
  ['teal', 'brown', 'tan'],
  ['orange', 'purple', 'black']
]

var boxed = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
   for (i = 0; i < boxed.length; i++) {
         
        boxed[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex][i];
        boxed[i].style.width = '100px';
        boxed[i].style.height = '100px';
        boxed[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
});
button.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <button>Theme</button>
```

Comment: Yes, thats good but i dont want to randomize the colors, for example the 3 divs should always either appear 'red', 'green', 'blue' or 'teal', 'brown', 'tan'.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const colors= [ ['red', 'green', 'blue']
              , ['teal', 'brown', 'tan']
              , ['orange', 'purple', 'black'] ]
  ,   boxed  = document.querySelectorAll(".box")
  ,   button = document.querySelector("button")
  ;
button.onclick=_=>
  {
  let colorN = Math.floor(Math.random() *3)
  boxed.forEach((box,i)=>
    {
    box.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorN][i];
    })
  }
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">box 1</div>
<div class="box">box 2</div>
<div class="box">box 3</div>

<button>change Colors</button>
```